Error importing sdk file after converting project from CRA to Vite
This is the error when starting vite's local development server:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'webpackJsonpthirdPartySDK')
My project uses a minified .js file from a third party SDK that was working fine with react-scripts and webpack. I'm getting the above error when importing the SDK file like this:
import * as thirdPartySDK from '../../../vendor/third-party-sdk'
I'm assuming the SDK file uses commonjs imports. Here's the start of the minified file:
(function(e,t){'object'==typeof exports&&'object'==typeof module?module.exports=t():'function'==typeof define
I was able to resolve a similar error with another imported SDK file using theviteCommonjs plugin. Any idea how I can resolve this?

Does this answer your question? React Vite: Exports from local modules not found (Migration from CRA)

@Mushroomator I don't have any tsconfig.json files in my project and the other proposed solution didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion!
